C# Is there a constraint for generics like MyClass<T1,T2> where 'T1 doesn't extend T2'
I'm implementing yet another Two-Way Dictionary that represents a bijective map.
I'd like to force the two types to be different, as to allow
class Map<T1, T2> {
    public T1 Get(T2 key) {
    }
    public T2 Get(T1 key) {
    }
}

instead of
class Map<T1, T2> {
    public T1 GetByB(T2 key) {
    }
    public T2 GetByA(T1 key) {
    }
}

as well as a safe [] operator.
The ideas i came up with are a runtime check with typeof(T1).IsAssignableFrom(..)
and/or defining some Map<T1,T1> to "overload" the safer <T1,T2> class (which i don't think is even doable let alone good)
but they feel terrible.
what i'm looking for is something along the line of
class Map<T1,T2> where T1 not: T2 where T2 not: T1 {
}


"I'd like to force the two types to be different" you can't do that with generics

The generic constraints is for the compiler to learn something about what T is, to allow you to do more things to it inside the method, not what it isn't. Also how would that map work if one of the types was object?

As @GSerg said I don't believe there is a constraint for this.  You could put the typeof(T1).IsAssignableFrom(..) in the static constructor if you don't want to do it every time an instance is constructed.  Also maybe you could make a Roslyn analyzer to give a warning when T1 == T2.

The first code snippet compiles, so what's the problem? If someone uses the same types such that the Get calls are ambiguous, that's their fault.
